# Page loads before stylesheet

Tags: load, stylesheet

I have an MVC website application and every few days I get a screen-shot from a client where the page loaded and the style sheet in the head of the page just seems to never have downloaded. I added the style sheet in the head of the page with a link type="text/css" href= tag.

The screen shot that I am sent show the page with no styles applied to it. I do not want to move style inline or add the styles internally with the styles sitting in the head of the document but how else can I make sure that the styles are loaded before the page renders?

Thank you
Jack

---

I am also blaming the proxy but there is no way may boss wants to fall for this. I am leaning towards that fact that the style sheet download times out but can I stop the page from downloading without it?

How can I get the style sheet to cache on the client in IIS7? I inspect the headers in Firefox and that is set to Cache-Control:private, must revalidate What I want is public and no must-revalidate

I have a cache duration of 356 days on the folder but no go.

Comment: If you can provide a link to the aforementioned website, this could help us zero-in on the problem much faster.

Answer (score 0):

Did you also add rel="stylesheet"?

Don't think it has something to do with your problem though.

Sure sounds like a local problem of your client (proxy???).

Answer (score 0):

Anything in the head section SHOULD be loaded before everything else. Unless a timeout occurs on the stylesheet, in which case the browser would just continue to load without it. 
Is it possible to replicate this problem in any way?
I also believe it is aa local problem. (timeout on css file)

The proper tag is:

```
<link href="special.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
```